# Symmetries of a triangular prism

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

With a triangular prism, we have the 2 equilateral on the end. The symmetries of the an equilateral triangle is 6. With this we deduce the 3D solid has $2\times6=12$ symmetries.

For the reflective symmetries we have four that reflects on planes that go through the end of the prism, and one that is perpendicular to the rectangular faces

[image: Reflections of triangular prism]

For the rotational symmetries, we can rotate through the triangular end by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$. We can also rotate around an axis that goes through the midpoint each rectangular edge that joins to another rectangular edge and through the opposing centre of the rectangular face, e.g.

[image: rotation of triangular symmetry]

So, that gives 4 reflection symmetries, and 5 rotational symmetries, and 1 identity. What am I missing with the two other symmetries?

Comment: Call the triangle at one end ABC and the triangle at the other end A'B'C'. Suppose you swap them by reflection about the centre plane and then rotate about the axis through the centres of the triangles by $\pm2\pi/3$. That gives two symmetries not in your list of 10.